# Async image downloader

Tags: iphone, image, user-interface, asynchronous, download

I have write a little class to perform the download of the images by using an NSURLConnection. 
The idea it's to delegate the download to this class to avoid to block the execution.

So I pass the target UIImageView (by ref) and the url to the function and start the download:

```
-(void)getImage:(UIImageView**)image formUrl:(NSString*)urlStr
{
    NSLog(@"Downloader.getImage.url.debug: %@",urlStr);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval:5.0];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
    NSURLConnection *c = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    [conn addObject:c];
    int i = [conn indexOfObject:c];
    [imgs insertObject:*image atIndex:i];
    [c release];
}
```

When it's finished set the image and update the imageView:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    int i = [conn indexOfObject:connection];

    NSData *rawData = [buffer objectAtIndex:i];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:rawData];
    UIImageView *imgView = [imgs objectAtIndex:i];
    imgView.image = img;

    [imgView setNeedsDisplay];

    [conn removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    [imgs removeObjectAtIndex:i];
    [buffer removeObjectAtIndex:i];

    if ([conn count]==0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
    }
}
```

This system works quite good, but i can't get updated the UIImageView inside the cells of a UITableViewCell, any idea ? (actually the cell it's updated when I click on it)
There is a better way to implement this functionality ? (actually the need are: non-blocking, caching system)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cesar

For async image loading, caching and threaded operation, I use SDImageCache class from http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage.  I also wrote my own several times, but this one is brilliant and I've thrown all my old code away.

From its documentation:

> Just `#import` the `UIImageView+WebCache.h` header, and call the `setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:` method from the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` UITableViewDataSource method. Everything will be handled for you, from async downloads to caching management.

Hilton

Comment: it works quite good, but i still have the same issues on the UITableCellView

Answer (score 3):

Simply follow the steps:

```
    1) Download SDWebImage below  And drag to your xcode project.
```

[Click here to Download the SDWebImage](http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

```
   2) Write the following code in your .h file #import "UIImageView+WebCache.h"
   3) Write the following code for your image view 
  [yourImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.sample.com/image.png"]];
```

Thats its... you have done!!!

Comment: tried to use SDWebImage but get 8 errors when i run it. "compat"-version brought up 10. is there any hint?

Comment: yes i do. the projects needed MapKit.framework and ImageIO.framework added to the "Link Binary With Libraries" in Build Phases.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSAutoreleasePool *pool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    [img_data setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.str_url]]]];
    [pool release];
```

Answer (score 1):

> This system works quite good, but i can't get updated the UIImageView
>   inside the cells of a UITableViewCell, any idea ? (actually the cell
>   it's updated when I click on it) There is a better way to implement
>   this functionality ? (actually the need are: non-blocking, caching
>   system

Have you tried using  **[tableView reloadData];**
Call it at the end of connectionDidFinishLoading method

Answer (score 1):

Use [SDWebImage](http://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) simply. I'm also using that one. Loading images smoothy. Am using below code to show the image from URL

```
[myImageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"www.sample.com/image.png"] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"lod.png"] 
success:^(UIImage *image, BOOL cached)
{
    productImageDetails.image = image;
} 
failure:^(NSError *error) {
    productImageDetails.image =[UIImage imageNamed:@"no_image.jpg"];
}];
```

*Success* part will display the image from webService. And, if there's any image failed to load or anyother failure issue you can load your own image there simply. [There](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.m) are more functionalities with that example. You can just refer it.