# iPhone - content won't scroll while image is loaded from URL

Tags: objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimageview

I'm trying to do something in my iPhone app where it downloads an image from a URL. The image downloads fine on the page, but I can't scroll through content or interact with it in any other way until the images download, making the app feels like it's frozen at first.

I've just used this code to load the image:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    *photo1.image = [UIImage imageWithData:
        [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
            [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ikipond.com/wp-includes/images/cosplayipn/will_1.png"]
         ]
    ];
}
```

I'd really appreciate a suggestion of how to make it so users can interact with the page while the images are still downloading. Thanks a lot,

Chris

Answer (score 1):

The `dataWithContentsOfURL:` method blocks until the download is complete, and is thus blocking the main (GUI) thread. You need to download the image asynchronously  (using `NSURLConnection`) or in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

do it on any thread but the main.

a place to start; [Async image downloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038726/async-image-downloader)